# Consistent way to get request payload in Flask

Tags: python, curl, flask

I have a Flask view that accepts some POST data. I can post the data with curl as form-encoded or JSON. How can I get the data no matter which way the client posts it?

```
from flask import request

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def refresh():
    # empty when posted as JSON
    print(request.form)
    # empty when posted as form-encoded
    print(request.data)
    return 'Hello, World!'
```

```
curl -XPOST -H "Content-Type: application/json" 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'
curl -XPOST 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'
curl -XGET 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/?thing1=1' -d '{"thing2":2}'
```

Comment: You read the API docs? http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request

Comment: Yes. I have definitely read the docs. After much puzzling, the observed behavior matches what it described in the docs. The docs do not describe a always-works method to access the request payload.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no attribute provided by Flask to get the parsed data in one place. You're expected to know what data your view accepts and do what's needed. Clients are expected to only pass data that the view accepts if they want their request to succeed.

[Flask-WTF provides a form class that picks from `form`, `files`, and `get_json` depending on what has data.](https://github.com/lepture/flask-wtf/blob/9cb0ac619f79a702254e1ad248ea8e15e5691d92/flask_wtf/form.py#L54-L68) You can do something similar.

```
from werkzeug.datastructures import CombinedMultiDict, ImmutableMultiDict

def form_or_json():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.files:
            return CombinedMultiDict((request.files, request.form))
        elif request.form:
            return request.form
        elif request.get_json():
            return ImmutableMultiDict(request.get_json())

# in a view
data = form_or_json()
```

If you want to get the raw data, without Flask processing it, use `request.get_data()`. This is typically not needed, and you should let Flask process form or JSON data.